# Why is my python function in pandas not returning any values?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am new to python and trying to create a simple price function

```
# create function to caluclate price:
def price_function(ds,us): # <- function Name is called 'price_function'
    """Calculates Price per Unit by using the following Equation: (Price per Unit = Dollar Sales/Unit Sales)
    
    Args:
        ds (float64): array of Dollar Sales.
        us (float64): array of Unit Sales
        
    Returns:
        float64: (Numpy Arrays)
    """
    # Create variables for Dollar Sales, Unit Sales and Price
    ds = np.array([df['Dollar Sales']])
    us = np.array([df['Unit Sales']])
    price = np.divide(ds,us)
    return price_function

# create a column called 'Price per Unit' and run the price_function using 'Dollar Sales' and 'Unit Sales' as the parameters
df['Price per Unit'] = price_function(df['Dollar Sales'], df['Unit Sales'])
df
```

My function will run but I get the following values for the new column I created: <function price_function at 0x000002C629EE5D38> '

Comment: It returns the function object "price_function", not the price array.

Comment: Typo: `return price_function` should be `return price`

Comment: it's undoubtedly the typo in the comment above the function ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As you are probably aware, you can do this without a function too:

```py
df['Price per Unit'] = df['Dollar Sales'] / df['Unit Sales']
```

If you want to use a function, the one you showed in the original question has a few issues:

1. while taking arguments `ds` and `us`, you ignore them and reach to the outer scope's `df`; this may lead to lots of head-scratching later;
2. the return value should be the value you just computed, `price`, instead of `price_function`, which is the function itself (a function object).

To use a function, you may do something like:

```py
def price_function(ds, us):
    """Calculate Price per Unit by using the following Equation:
      Price per Unit = Dollar Sales/Unit Sales
    
    Args:
        ds (pd.Series): Dollar Sales.
        us (pd.Series): Unit Sales
        
    Returns:
        (pd.Series): the ratio of ds / us
    """
    per_unit =  ds / us
    return per_unit
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `price_function` instead of `price`. You can correct it, or just use the following:

df['Price per Unit'] = df['Dollar Sales'] / df['Unit Sales']

**Your code can be corrected as**

```
# create function to caluclate price:
def price_function(ds,us): # <- function Name is called 'price_function'
    """Calculates Price per Unit by using the following Equation: (Price per Unit = Dollar Sales/Unit Sales)
    
    Args:
        ds (float64): array of Dollar Sales.
        us (float64): array of Unit Sales
        
    Returns:
        float64: (Numpy Arrays)
    """
    # Create variables for Dollar Sales, Unit Sales and Price
    ds = np.array([df['Dollar Sales']])
    us = np.array([df['Unit Sales']])
    price = np.divide(ds,us)
    return price

# create a column called 'Price per Unit' and run the price_function using 'Dollar Sales' and 'Unit Sales' as the parameters
df['Price per Unit'] = price_function(df['Dollar Sales'], df['Unit Sales'])
df
```